# How do I stop my Galaxy S5 phone from waking in my pocket?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I had this problem when I had an HTC One M8 and now I have it with my Samsung Galaxy S5: I will get a notification and my screen will wake-up in my pocket and cause all sorts of bothers (skipping songs, taking pictures, etc).

Is there some option in Android OS to stop the screen from waking up when it receives a notification? I have googled this issue and all I see is suggesting involving rooting the phone and buying new cases, but nothing that directly addresses the issue. This is frustrating because it seems like it would be so simple to have the phone not wake upon getting a notification. Is there such option?

Answer (score 0):

> cause all sorts of bothers (skipping songs, taking pictures, etc)

Is the touch sensitive option enabled. As it will increase the touch sensitivity, your device will work abnormally for any touch like sensations (like that of keeping in your pocket).

> Is there some option in Android OS to stop the screen from waking up when it receives a notification?

I guess not in our S5's stock firmware. So you either use external methods to stop it or turn off the touch sensitive and decrease the screen timeout.